# How to find the polarity of a surface (such as ZnO 000-1)?

Tags: surfaces

The 0001 and 000-1 surfaces of ZnO are polar, while the other surfaces like 101̅0 and 112̅0 are nonpolar (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.chemmater.7b01487)).
How can one determine what is the polarity of any surface?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if you have any update for us, since it's been over 7 months? Did you figure out the answer? Is this still a problem for you?

Comment: Unfortunately @NikeDattani, I haven't been able to figure out a solution to this